Determine whether a Pandas dataframe Column has values present in another pandas dataframe column
I have the first dataframe (df_animal)



animal




cat


dog


bird


rat


fish



I have the second dataframe  (df_content)



document_content




cat in the hat


the dog was hungry


when pigs fly


cat


the fish swam up river


the bug crawled


the rat scurried


rat


the cow mooed



I want to produce a new column (in_document_content) with True/False values in the df_animal dataframe that would show if the animal in the animal column appeared in the df_content document_content column. It would look like this:



animal
in_document_content




cat
True


dog
True


bird
False


rat
True


fist
True



I tried this:
df_compare = df_animals.assign(in_docContent = df_animals.animal.isin(df_content.document_content))

And I got this output:
df_compare
The isin method is not working how I though it would, and animals like dog and fish are showing False instead of True. For instance the word 'dog' appears in 'the dog was hungry' and 'fish' appears in 'the fish swam up river'

You'll notice that you're only getting a True result if the animal appears exactly in the document, not if it is a partial match. What you are looking for is an operation that tests if the animal is part of any of the texts in the document_content column.

You'll notice that you're only getting a True result if the animal appears exactly in the document, not if it is a partial match. What you are looking for is an operation that tests if the animal is part of any of the texts in the document_content column.
This would do the trick: column.str.contains('value').any()
In something similar to your example:
import pandas as pd

df_animal = pd.DataFrame(
    {"animal": [
        "cat",
        "dog",
        "bird",
        "whale",
        "shark"]
    })
df_content = pd.DataFrame(
    {"document_content": [
        "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
        "The cat in the hat.",
        "The bird is the word.",
        "The fish is a dish.",
        "Shark"]
    })

df_compare = pd.DataFrame()
df_compare['animal'] = df_animal.animal
df_compare['in_content'] = df_compare.animal.apply(
    lambda part: df_content.document_content.str.contains(part).any())

print(df_compare)

Output:
  animal  in_content
0    cat        True
1    dog        True
2   bird        True
3  whale       False
4  shark       False

Note that this is case-sensitive, 'shark' wasn't found, since there's only 'Shark'.

In addition to points added by @Grismar, you can optimize the runtime & control the case-sensitive and case-insensitive using the following:
Method 1. case-sensitive version (baseline).
Shark will be False
df_compare = pd.DataFrame()
df_compare['animal'] = df_animal.animal
df_compare['in_content'] = df_compare.animal.apply(
    lambda part: df_content.document_content.str.contains(part).any())
# >>> 942 µs ± 9.19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

Method2a: case-sensitive version.
Shark will be False
txt = " ".join(set(df_content["document_content"]))
df_compare = pd.DataFrame([
    {"animal":e, "in_document_content": e in txt} for e in df_animal["animal"]
])
# >>> 126 µs ± 2.58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

Method 2b: case in-sensitive version.
Shark will be True
txt = " ".join(set(df_content["document_content"])).lower()
df_compare = pd.DataFrame([
    {"animal":e, "in_document_content": e.lower() in txt} for e in df_animal["animal"]
])
# >>> 130 µs ± 2.11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)


Thank-you very much! That helps immensely, especially with the case sense!
